# Can't load replays?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've downloaded [some replays](http://www.sc2win.com/starcraft-2-replays/replay-packages/demuslim-replay-package/), but when I try to load them in SC2 I get an error:

> Unable to open replay.

Does anybody know what the problem might be here, and how I might go about resolving it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just downloaded the replay pack myself, and sure enough, none of them works.

Corrupted files maybe?

EDIT: I've just noticed the date this replay pack got posted (5th of March, 2010) - it was essentially before the official release, so that might explain why.